# PHPExcel | While loop inside while loop doesn't work properly

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have some SQL data that I want to pass to an Excel document using PHPExcel.

There are 3 tables:

1. Books:

   1.1 bookID

   1.2 bookName
2. Tags:

   2.1 tagID

   2.2 tagName
3. Post_Tags:

   3.1 id

   3.2 tagID

   3.3 bookID

I want the tags to be in the second column of the xls sheet, seperated by commas. So here I have a while loop inside a while loop.

**The problem:**

In the produced excel sheet, not all the book's tags are listed in each column B's cell, but only a single tag.

Any ideas why? Thanks in advance :)

```
require_once "includes/config.php";
require_once "includes/functions.php";
require_once 'phptoxls/PHPExcel.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$F = $objPHPExcel -> getActiveSheet();


/*      START: RECORDS      */

$line = 2;
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `books`') or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

$bookID = $row['bookID'];
$bookName = $row['bookName'];

$query2 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `books`
                    INNER JOIN `post_tags`
                    ON post_tags.bookID = books.bookID
                    INNER JOIN `tags`
                    ON tags.tagID = post_tags.tagID
                    WHERE books.bookID = "'.$bookID.'"') or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($query2) > 0){
    $rowNum = mysql_num_rows($query2);
    $i = 1;
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)){
        $tags = $row1['tagName'];
        if($i < $rowNum){
            $tags .= ', ';
        }
    }
}

    $F  -> setCellValue('A'.$line, $bookName)
        -> setCellValue('B'.$line, $tags);

    ++$line;
}

/*      END: RECORDS        */


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="books.xls');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here lies your issue:

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)){
    $tags = $row1['tagName'];
```

You are resetting the value of $tags with every loop. To get it working with the code you supplied simply do the following:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query2) > 0){
    $rowNum = mysql_num_rows($query2);
    $i = 1;
    $tags = "";
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)){
        $tags .= $row1['tagName'];
        if($i < $rowNum){
            $tags .= ', ';
        }
    }
}
```

I would however suggest you fix it by doing this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query2) > 0){
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)){
        $tags[] = $row1['tagName'];
    }
    $tags = implode(', ',$tags);
}
```

Comment: I added the brackets, but now I receive the following error: Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings

Comment: Updated my answer. Please note that I have done more than just add brackets. :)

Comment: Thank you DarkRanger! However I managed to overcome this problem by simply adding unset($tags); before the outer while loop ends. What method, do you think, is the best?

Comment: Depends on the size of your application. If you have 4 books and do it your way, performance won't really be impacted. But get to 10 000, 20 000 books, then all those bits and bobs make a massive impact on performance. If I were you, I'd try to do it correct from day one, so I'd probably go with my suggested fix. Might still not be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please indent your code better, because it's almost unreadable(http://beta.phpformatter.com). Second: I think you just concatenating the tags with ','-s. Dude seriously at the beginning of your 1st while:

```
<?php
require_once "includes/config.php";
require_once "includes/functions.php";
require_once 'phptoxls/PHPExcel.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$F = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();


/*      START: RECORDS      */

$line = 2;
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `books`') or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $all_tags_for_one_row = '';
    $bookID = $row['bookID'];
    $bookName = $row['bookName'];

    $query2 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `books`
                    INNER JOIN `post_tags`
                    ON post_tags.bookID = books.bookID
                    INNER JOIN `tags`
                    ON tags.tagID = post_tags.tagID
                    WHERE books.bookID = "' . $bookID . '"') or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($query2) > 0) {
        $rowNum = mysql_num_rows($query2);
        $i = 1;
        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
            $tags = $row1['tagName'];
            if ($i < $rowNum) {

                $all_tags_for_one_row .= ($i != $rowNum ? $tags . ', ' : $tags ); 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }

    $F->setCellValue('A' . $line, $bookName);
    $F->setCellValue('B' . $line, $all_tags_for_one_row);

    ++$line;
}

/*      END: RECORDS        */


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="books.xls');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
?>
```